Create static variable inside of \pgfplotstableset definition
I try to understand, how to create a variable inside or outside of the \pgfplotstableset environement which is static and will not be resetted all the time.
Probably this is a generic question for variables inside of the Preamble and not just related to the \pgfplotstableset environement, but here I mentioned this problem now.
To keep it short, I just want check some contents of my generated tables before I print them. So usually I parse through all cells and check the content of the Value column in regards of the Type column.
In this MWE I just have two Types (typA / typB). When typA occurs, the content of the Value field should be stored and all following rows with typB should be checked if the same value is taken (refTypeA0 in the first case).
The value of typB components should only change, if there is a new typA with a new Value. Afterwards all following typB's should be checked to have the new reference value (refTypeA1 in this case).
The problem is, that \newcommand{\lastTypeA}{0} will be resetted very often and will not keep the stored values.
How can I achieve this?
MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Type,Value
typA,refTypeA0
typB,refTypeA0
typB,refTypeA0
typB,refTypeA1   %=> This should create an error!  refTypeA0 != refTypeA1
typA,refTypeA1
typB,refTypeA1 
typB,refTypeA2   %=> This should also create an error! refTypeA1 != refTypeA2
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}

\newcommand{\lastTypeA}{0}

\pgfplotstableset{
    assign cell content/.code={%
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{typA}}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Value}\of{\csvdata}
                \renewcommand{\lastTypeA}{\pgfplotsretval} % This content is lost!
            }{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Value}\of{\csvdata}
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{\lastTypeA}}{
                     All right!\newline
                }{
                     Wrong type!\newline
                }
            }
        \fi
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}

Current Result

Expected Result


I deleted my answer, as it didn't produce the desired output. You should maybe give an example of the expected result.

@jlab Good Idea! I added the current result and the expected one :)

@jlab Can you maybe tell me, why the \newcommand variables in the Preamble are volatile and can not be made static? I think this is the main root cause for the disfunction. So they are reacting different to variables which are used after \begin{document}.

It doesn't depend if \newcommand is done before or after \begin{document}, it's only a matter of scope. \newcommand{\lastTypeA}{0} is set globally (\lastTypeA means 0 everywere). But \renewcommand{\lastTypeA}{\pgfplotsretval} is lost at the end of the group (next }); after \lastTypeA means 0 again.

@PascalS "Can you maybe tell me, why the \newcommand variables in the Preamble are volatile and can not be made static?" Actually when it is about macro programming in LaTeX, there are no variables. Only tokenization, expansion and scoping and macros, i.e., control sequences which are tokens and which in the stage of expansion get removed from the token stream whereafter tokens are gathered from the token stream as arguments and tokens are delivered as replacement text with parameters of the macro-definition's  replaced by the tokens that were gathered as the arguments.

Defining \lastTypeA globally and hereby toplevel-expanding \pgfplotsretval might do the trick.
I also added some % here and there to prevent the coming into being of probably unwanted space tokens that yield horizontal glue when processed while LaTeX is typesetting things in horizontal mode.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Type,Value
typA,refTypeA0
typB,refTypeA0
typB,refTypeA0
typB,refTypeA1   %=> This should create an error!  refTypeA0 != refTypeA1
typA,refTypeA1
typB,refTypeA1 
typB,refTypeA2   %=> This should also create an error! refTypeA1 != refTypeA2
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}

\newcommand{\lastTypeA}{0}

\pgfplotstableset{%
    assign cell content/.code={%
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1 %
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{typA}}{%
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Value}\of{\csvdata}%
                \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\lastTypeA\expandafter{\pgfplotsretval}% 
            }{%
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Value}\of{\csvdata}%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{\lastTypeA}}{%
                     All right!\newline
                }{%
                     Wrong type!\newline
                }%
            }%
        \fi
    },%
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}%
\end{document}



Cool this works. I don‘t really understand why, but it works! Could you just explain why it works? :)

In my answer I already said everything that needs to be said to understand. If you don't understand anyway, then you lack knowledge of the basic concepts and of the programming paradigm of TeX and you should read the TeXbook or a similarly good introduction.
